# How to get Model values in Controller

Tags: ember.js

Trying to get the value of a clicked `item` in controller's `action` (alert) but I always get `undefined`. I would like to return JSON (multiple entries) from model and access it in controller (without using `FixtureAdapter`).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="first">
...        
{{#each item in model}}
  <p {{action 'myClick'}}>{{item.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
...

App.FirstRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return [
            {name: 'Ruby'},
            {name: 'Java'}
        ]
        //return [ 'Ruby', 'Java', 'Scala'];
    }
});

App.FirstController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title:'data from FirstController',
  actions: {
      myClick: function() {
          alert('action in controller -> ' + this.get('model').get('name'));
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you pass your item as parameter to your action?

```
{{#each item in model}}
  <p {{aciton 'myClick' item}}> {{item.name}} </p>
{{/each}}


App.FirstController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  title:'data from FirstController',
  actions: {
    myClick: function(item) {
      alert('action in controller -> ' + item.name);
    }
  }
});
```

By the way you are not returning `Ember.Object` in your route. Your model is array of pure javascript object so instead of `item.get('name')` use `item.name`

Comment: Brilliant Idea. But I got `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in console.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to provide JSBin example that demonstrates your problem. I could fix it