# Getter / Setter or direct reference?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Learning Ember.js and have a reasonable understanding of getters and setters (accessors) through Ruby and Java.

In Ember/Javascript, I seem to have a very serious lack of understanding. For instance in my controllers/models, I don't have a clue whether to use `object.set(property,value)` or refer them directly `object.property = 'value'`

As an example, in my earlier question ([How to get Model values in Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483333/how-to-get-model-values-in-controller)), part of working answer was to use `object.name` instead of `object.get('name')`. It worked but I miss the basic understanding.

Would appreciate some clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is: You should always use `.get()/.set()` when you are in your .js-files. When you are in your templates (.hbs or other) you should not (you can't do it).

If you access a property via `myObj.myProp` it will work for regular properties, but computed ones won't. If you set a property via `myObj.myProp` you can still get the value back, but bindings and observers won't be notified that it has changed and won't updated properly.

This is a design decision by the Ember team which allows for efficient bindings/observers instead of doing dirty-checking of all bound/observed properties (which is what Angular currently does).

I made a small jsbin showing this. Three values are bound initially, the button then changes one and logs it into the console (so make sure to have the console open), the binding isn't updated but the value can be retrieved. It then tries to get a computed property via `myObj.myProp` which returns undefined and then the regular way.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cipapaxevi/2/

Also, as a side note. If you want a property thats on a child object to what you have you can access it via `myObj.get('myProp.myOtherProp')` instead of doing `myObj.get('myProp').get('myOtherProp')`. It saves you from the worry that `myProp` could return `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Javascript works and it's one of its disadvantages. It doesn't have public/private proprieties nor methods. Therefore, we should rely on good comments in the code.

I am not an expert in Ember, but when I face the similar problems in JS I usually look at the source code of the library to see how it's constructed and then make a decision. That's why probably js libraries are usually shipped with both min and dev versions.

However, if the object has special methods to access its properties then they are there for a reason, so use them instead of the direct access to the properties. As I said above, in Js you can't make properties be private or protected.